# New to Scheme/Racket: Heavy use of recursion a way of life or am I just going through a typical phase

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I've been bouncing around functional languages for the last few months from F# to Haskell to Scheme (Racket).  I've never really used recursion much, but Haskell and its pattern matching really helped me to be less afraid of them.  Now that I'm using Scheme, I seem to default to recursive methods.  I'm curious if this is indicative of just going through an "ooo shiny!" phase or if recursion is a staple of Scheme development.

Side note: I've been shooting for tail recursion whenever I write recursive methods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it depends what type of recursion you're talking about.

The first eye-opener (for instance if you're working through SICP) is that iteration can be replaced by recursion. All those lines of tedious and error-prone loop code you've written in a past life, can be done another way. This is a cool and (as you put it) "ooh shiny!" experience.

The next eye-opener is how little of *that* sort of recursive code you'll actually write in real life. Instead, you'll avoid tedious iteration -- *and* tedious recursion, both -- by using building blocks like `map` and `fold`.

Furthermore in Racket you'll probably graduate from `map` and `fold` to preferring the "comprehensions" like `for/list`, `for/vector`, and `for/fold` that work on sequences not just lists.  Up the food chain you keep going.

Having said that, there are some problems you will best solve recursively (not just "iteration by other means"). And the comfort level you got in eye-opener number one, will help there, I think.

Comment: +1 Learning to use--and eventually rolling your own--higher-order functions is definitely the next "Ooh shiny!" step you should be taking. After that, then perhaps monads and arrows.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not a phase, it is a staple.  Recursion is a technique that allows you to solve more complex problems than you otherwise would be able to tackle easily—and even in cases where you want an iterative solution, it's easier to arrive at that if you first formulate a recursive one.

Mastering recursion also opens up new problem areas to you.  Typical iterative-only programmers are not equipped to deal with problems that, for example, involve manipulating and translating between formal languages like, e.g., writing complex SQL query generators on the basis of an *encoded description* of the report the user wants to see.

If you want to move forward, you should look into getting more comfortable with folds, which abstract away from explicit recursion by separating the recursive structure of a computation from the content of the recursive steps.  So for example Scheme's `fold-right` can be seen as "perform a recursive computation that has the same shape as this list, mapping the empty list to this value as the base case, and each `cons` to this function."  Then there's folds on other, more complex data structures.

Answer (score 3):

It's a little of each. Recursion is a staple of Lisp in general (not just Scheme). More advanced users, however, frequently make more use of other control flow primitives (although they may, in turn, be implemented recursively).